# Recurrence Relations in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, recurrence

I am working with the recurrence "x<sub>n+1</sub> = (13/3)x<sub>n</sub> - (4/3)x<sub>n-1</sub>". I am trying to write a Python script to print the first 50 values of x<sub>n</sub> with the given values of x<sub>0</sub> = 1 and x<sub>1</sub> = 1/3. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
import math
def printRecurrence():
    x = [0]*51 #initialize list of x values
    x[0] = 1
    x[1] = 1/3
    for i in range(1, 51):
        x[i+1] = (13/3)*x[i] - (4/3)*x[i-1]
        print(x[i])
```

and the output I receive is:

```
0.3333333333333333
0.11111111111111094
0.03703703703703626
0.012345679012342514
0.004115226337435884
0.0013717421124321456
0.00045724737062478524
0.00015241578946454185
5.0805260179967644e-05
1.6935074827137338e-05
5.644977344304949e-06
1.8814687224716613e-06
6.263946716372672e-07
2.0575194713260943e-07
5.63988753916179e-08
-2.994080281313502e-08
-2.049419793790756e-07
-8.481608402251475e-07
-3.402107668470205e-06
-1.361158544307069e-05
-5.444739336201271e-05
-0.00021778992397796082
-0.0008711598127551465
-0.0034846392899683535
-0.013938557172856001
-0.05575422869575153
-0.22301691478444863
-0.8920676591382753
-3.5682706365532617
-14.2730825462131
-57.092330184852415
-228.36932073940963
-913.4772829576384
-3653.909131830553
-14615.63652732221
-58462.546109288836
-233850.18443715532
-935400.7377486213
-3741602.950994485
-14966411.80397794
-59865647.21591176
-239462588.86364704
-957850355.4545882
-3831401421.8183527
-15325605687.27341
-61302422749.09364
-245209690996.37457
-980838763985.4983
-3923355055941.993
```

which is only correct for the first 13 printed values. The proof I was provided was that x<sub>n</sub> = 3<sup>-n</sup>, which for the most part does not match the values of my script. Did I do something wrong in my calculations? I've been unable to see it.

Comment: floating point accumulation error I suppose...

Comment: What version of Python?  In Python2.x, 1/3 is zero, and 13/3 and 4/3 is 4 and 1, respectively.

Comment: @Max it has to be python 3. Because else no result would be floating point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This recurrence relation can be answered exactly through the use of the `fractions` module or with a variable level of precision using the `decimal` module, which demonstrates the very high level of precision required to find compute 50 iterations accurately.

Jean-François' point about floating point accumulation errors is correct. However the `fraction` module does not seem to be able to multiply multiple `Fraction` objects together, so all of the numeric values must be stated within the fraction object. Credit to him for the use of the correct module for this problem.

**Exact answer**

```
import math
import fractions

def printRecurrence():
    x = [0]*51 #initialize list of x values
    x[0] = fractions.Fraction(1,1)
    x[1] = fractions.Fraction(1,3)
    for i in range(1, 50):
        x[i+1] = fractions.Fraction(13*x[i]/3) - fractions.Fraction(4*x[i-1]/3)
        print(float(x[i+1]), 3**(-(i+1)), x[i+1]-(3)**(-(i+1)))

printRecurrence()
```

The print-out shows that the computation exactly matches the proof answer.

**Inexact but instructive answer**

The `decimal` module allows for a custom level of precision; to get to 50 iterations one needs a precision of 60 points or more.

```
import math
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 60

def printRecurrence():
    x = [0]*51 #initialize list of x values
    x[0] = Decimal(1)
    x[1] = Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)
    for i in range(1, 50):
        x[i+1] = (Decimal(13)/Decimal(3))*x[i] - (Decimal(4)/Decimal(3))*x[i-1]
        print(float(x[i+1]), 3**(-(i+1)), float(x[i+1]-Decimal(3)**(-(i+1))))

printRecurrence()
```

As with Jean-François' answer, I've printed the result, the computed value of 3**-n and the difference. One can play with the precision level `getcontext().prec` to see the effect on the result.

```
0.111111111111 0.111111111111 -1e-60
0.037037037037 0.037037037037 -4e-60
0.0123456790123 0.0123456790123 -1.57e-59
0.00411522633745 0.00411522633745 -6.243e-59
0.00137174211248 0.00137174211248 -2.4961e-58
0.000457247370828 0.000457247370828 -9.984e-58
0.000152415790276 0.000152415790276 -3.993577e-57
5.08052634253e-05 5.08052634253e-05 -1.59742978e-56
1.69350878084e-05 1.69350878084e-05 -6.38971879e-56
5.64502926948e-06 5.64502926948e-06 -2.5558875048e-55
1.88167642316e-06 1.88167642316e-06 -1.02235500146e-54
6.27225474386e-07 6.27225474386e-07 -4.08942000567e-54
2.09075158129e-07 2.09075158129e-07 -1.63576800226e-53
6.96917193763e-08 6.96917193763e-08 -6.54307200905e-53
2.32305731254e-08 2.32305731254e-08 -2.61722880362e-52
7.74352437514e-09 7.74352437514e-09 -1.04689152145e-51
2.58117479171e-09 2.58117479171e-09 -4.18756608579e-51
8.60391597238e-10 8.60391597238e-10 -1.67502643432e-50
2.86797199079e-10 2.86797199079e-10 -6.70010573727e-50
9.55990663597e-11 9.55990663597e-11 -2.68004229491e-49
3.18663554532e-11 3.18663554532e-11 -1.07201691796e-48
1.06221184844e-11 1.06221184844e-11 -4.28806767185e-48
3.54070616147e-12 3.54070616147e-12 -1.71522706874e-47
1.18023538716e-12 1.18023538716e-12 -6.86090827496e-47
3.93411795719e-13 3.93411795719e-13 -2.74436330998e-46
1.3113726524e-13 1.3113726524e-13 -1.09774532399e-45
4.37124217466e-14 4.37124217466e-14 -4.39098129597e-45
1.45708072489e-14 1.45708072489e-14 -1.75639251839e-44
4.85693574962e-15 4.85693574962e-15 -7.02557007356e-44
1.61897858321e-15 1.61897858321e-15 -2.81022802942e-43
5.39659527735e-16 5.39659527735e-16 -1.12409121177e-42
1.79886509245e-16 1.79886509245e-16 -4.49636484708e-42
5.99621697484e-17 5.99621697484e-17 -1.79854593883e-41
1.99873899161e-17 1.99873899161e-17 -7.19418375532e-41
6.66246330538e-18 6.66246330538e-18 -2.87767350213e-40
2.22082110179e-18 2.22082110179e-18 -1.15106940085e-39
7.40273700597e-19 7.40273700597e-19 -4.60427760341e-39
2.46757900199e-19 2.46757900199e-19 -1.84171104136e-38
8.22526333997e-20 8.22526333997e-20 -7.36684416545e-38
2.74175444666e-20 2.74175444666e-20 -2.94673766618e-37
9.13918148886e-21 9.13918148886e-21 -1.17869506647e-36
3.04639382962e-21 3.04639382962e-21 -4.71478026589e-36
1.01546460987e-21 1.01546460987e-21 -1.88591210636e-35
3.38488203291e-22 3.38488203291e-22 -7.54364842542e-35
1.12829401097e-22 1.12829401097e-22 -3.01745937017e-34
3.76098003645e-23 3.76098003657e-23 -1.20698374807e-33
1.25366001171e-23 1.25366001219e-23 -4.82793499227e-33
4.17886668798e-24 4.1788667073e-24 -1.93117399691e-32
1.39295549185e-24 1.3929555691e-24 -7.72469598763e-32
```

Comment: and that's _very_ good. I was doing `Decimal(4/3)` which is stupid :) more upvotes for the man please.

Comment: I still don't understand why it fails with `fractions` even when converting num/denom to `decimal` before performing the division.

Comment: It turns out that you can get the right answer with `fractions` if you include the previous elements of the array in the fraction definition:
`fractions.Fraction(13*x[i]/3) - fractions.Fraction(4*x[i-1]/3)`
So the error seems to be the interpretation of the multiplication operator `*` with two Fraction objects.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've kind of combined our answers - this question turned out to be unexpectedly interesting!

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing *floating point accumulation error*.

Since current result depends on previous result, and float type is just an approximation, the more recurrences you're running, the more the accumulation error increases.

Since you're dealing with rational number, I'd advise the `fraction` module.

```
import fractions
def printRecurrence():
    x = [0]*51 #initialize list of x values
    x[0] = fractions.Fraction(1,1)
    x[1] = fractions.Fraction(1,3)
    for i in range(1, 50):
        x[i+1] = fractions.Fraction(13/3)*x[i] - fractions.Fraction(4/3)*x[i-1]
        print(float(x[i]),3**(-i),x[i]-3**(-i))
```

printRecurrence()

I've printed the result, the computed value of `3**-n` and the difference:

```
0.3333333333333333 0.3333333333333333 0.0
0.11111111111111109 0.1111111111111111 -1.3877787807814457e-17
0.037037037037036924 0.037037037037037035 -1.1102230246251565e-16
0.01234567901234521 0.012345679012345678 -4.683753385137379e-16
0.004115226337446681 0.00411522633744856 -1.878705524482882e-15
0.001371742112475337 0.0013717421124828531 -7.516123140538511e-15
0.0004572473707975519 0.0004572473708276177 -3.006584781486965e-14
0.00015241579015560884 0.00015241579027587258 -1.2026374362518466e-13
5.080526294423582e-05 5.080526342529086e-05 -4.810550354871108e-13
1.6935085884210096e-05 1.6935087808430286e-05 -1.9242201893822884e-12
5.645021572595982e-06 5.645029269476762e-06 -7.696880780399043e-12
1.8816456356357935e-06 1.8816764231589208e-06 -3.0787523127313645e-11
6.27102324293796e-07 6.272254743863069e-07 -1.2315009251094865e-10
2.0858255775872449e-07 2.0907515812876897e-07 -4.926003700444828e-10
6.772131789607814e-08 6.969171937625632e-08 -1.9704014801781827e-09
1.534896720470598e-08 2.3230573125418773e-08 -7.881605920712794e-09
-2.378289930771161e-08 7.743524375139592e-09 -3.15264236828512e-08
-1.2352451993969162e-07 2.581174791713197e-09 -1.2610569473140483e-07
-5.035623873283815e-07 8.603915972377324e-10 -5.044227789256192e-07
-2.0174043185033973e-06 2.8679719907924413e-10 -2.0176911157024764e-06
-8.070668863743547e-06 9.559906635974805e-11 -8.070764462809906e-06
-3.228302598488417e-05 3.186635545324935e-11 -3.228305785123962e-05
...
```

After 20 recurrences, the difference increases, but it's already much better.

EDIT: David answer made me realize that the fraction to float conversion spoils it all.

The `fraction` module only performs a division between 2 exact computed integers, but conversion to float ruins the precision.

Comment: Great answer, although… there as to be an intended lesson in that homework problem and I wonder whether "use fraction" is it…

Comment: the homework problem is probably intended to show you that computers have limited precision.

Comment: Are you sure it's 3**-n that gets inaccurate? 3**-n should always be a positive number. Using the `decimal` library to 60+ decimal places precision I find it matches all the way to 50 iterations. Something odd seems to be happening when converting back to float.

Comment: maybe you'd like to post a solution based on `decimal`. It would be interesting. I have tested with decimal and I don't have better results. I think that the fractions module should be the best choice since it manipulates only integers.

Comment: Could that be due to the level of precision? It wasn't until 60+ iterations that I saw an effect, 50 or so points of precision became negative before the iterations were complete. In any case I've added my answer.

Comment: That hadn't even occurred to me, I also didn't think I'd need another library but this was super helpful. And I agree with other commenters that this was most likely to show the limitations of precision in computing.